# Ehcache reload from DB on demand (manual refresh)

Tags: java, ehcache

I wanted to clear the cache (ehcache) and reload from DB (I wanted to this to manually refresh for some of our requirement). For that in a method I have used

```
CacheManager.removalAll();
```

After that I have tried two ways but I get same error as mentioned below (may be something wrong here)

**1)**

```
for (String cacheName : cacheNames) {
    cache = lvCacheMgr.addCache(cacheName);
}
```

2)

```
for (String cacheName : cacheNames) {
    lvCacheMgr.addCache(cacheName);
    cache = lvCacheMgr.getCache(name);
    cache.initialise();
}
```

then I am getting error as follows

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache Cache is not alive.
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2199)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1354)
    at org.hibernate.cache.EhCache.get(EhCache.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.get(StandardQueryCache.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultFromQueryCache(Loader.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2096)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CacheManager.removeAll` is a method that removes `Cache`s from the `CacheManager` and not a method that clears `Cache` content.

If you want to do the later, you need to invoke `Cache.removeAll` where you can access all caches from the `CacheManager` itself.